# Unable to decode weight machine value when bluetooth weight scale in KG mode in flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

My weight scale has two modes:

**when the device is in-lb(pound mode)** the decode output response is correct

DEVICE OUTPUT :[3, 52, 18, 224, 7, 2, 25, 3, 49, 28]

EXPECTED VALUE: 46.6lb

ACTUAL VALUE : 46.6lb

**When DEVICE IS IN LB MODE the output is CORRECT using below code**

`double getWeight(List<int> data, index) {.                                                           return (( 0xff & data[index + 1] ) << 8 | ( 0xff & data[index] ) << 0 ) / 100;                           }`

Refer below link for the above code details:
[Flutter ble read weight scale characteristic value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68233478/flutter-ble-read-weight-scale-characteristic-value)

But **When the device unit is KG MODE**, **the decode output response is wrong**

DEVICE OUTPUT :[2, 168, 12, 224, 7, 2, 25, 3, 51, 7]

EXPECTED VALUE: 46.7 lb

MY DECODED VALUE:32.4 lb

Consume please guide to decode it proper way for this issue?

Comment: In this link they have mentioned to convert output to kg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118489/ios-swift-mi-scale-2-bluetooth-get-weight.  but the converted output is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look for "`3.244 Weight Scale Measurement`" in the following document:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/gatt-specification-supplement-6/

It says about the weight field:

> This field is in kilograms with resolution 0.005 if the bit 0 of the
> Flag field is 0 or in pounds with a resolution of
> 0.01 if the bit 0 of the Flag field is 1.

So if the flag suggests you are in KG then you function is:

```
double getKgWeight(List<int> data, index) {
  return (( 0xff & data[index + 1] ) << 8 | ( 0xff & data[index] ) << 0 ) * 0.005;
}
```

For lbs:

```
double getlbsWeight(List<int> data, index) {
  return (( 0xff & data[index + 1] ) << 8 | ( 0xff & data[index] ) << 0 ) * 0.01;
}
```